# Apache strange behavior with $_SESSION variables on large PHP files

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I have a large PHP file with a lot of HTML and CSS followed by a section of PHP code.
However, if I add more than **4199** characters before the PHP code begins, the PHP code is <del>never</del> not properly executed (the server still sends the HTML after the PHP section).
But if I run the PHP file from the commandline it works fine.

So I guess that the problem is the Apache server configuration that somehow limits the size of executed PHP file.

---

System:

- Ubuntu-Server 20.10
- Apache/2.4.46 (Ubuntu)
- PHP 7.4.9 (cli)

```html
<?php code that works just fine ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
<div> lots of HTML (4200+ characters) </div>
    
<?php code that is not properly executed ?>
    
<div> more HTML that gets transmitted by the server </div>
    
</html>
```

Does anybody know where I can change this limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I in `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini` I've found the option `output_buffering = 4096` wiche I've now increased so that my whole PHP file is within that limit.

---

Apparently the problem had to do with a PHP **session** that was declared **after** the first **4096** bytes where send. (I think the session was not poperly set by the browser due to the "splitting" of the data transfer)

But I'm not sure if that was realy the problem.
I've also tried `session_start();` at the beginning of the file but that didn't solved the problem.

@Hannes thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the php file is only checked at the beginning for performance reasons. If there are no php statements it is treated as regular text/html file.

So if you only need a solution for the problem, add at the beginning something like

`<?php echo; ?>`

Then the file should be recognized as php file and you can add as many html tags as you like before your actually php code begins.